# Why: Index out of range error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import sys

v0 = float(sys.argv[1])
t = float(sys.argv[2])

g = 9.81

x = v0 * t - 0.5 * g *t **2
print (x)
```

When I run it, I get

> IndexError: list index out of range.

Why's that? And how can I fix it?

Comment: ... so, how are you calling this script?

Comment: Could you clarify what line of code is returning the IndexError? From your code it seems like v0 and t are referencing an indexed value, so possibly you aren't passing in the arguments correctly? How are you calling the script?

Comment: @Geralt.O.Rivia Line nr 3. v0 = float(sys.argv[1]). I understand that I have to call the scripts, but I'm confused to why when I gave this code to one of my friends and he just copied and pasted it and it worked for him.I guess I'll try something else.

Comment: @Geralt.O.Rivia is it maybe because "sys" is not imported in the system?

Comment: As Juanpa asked, you need to tell us *how you are running this*. `sys.argv[1]` means the first command-line argument (after the script name). So, are you actually using any command-line arguments?

Comment: @Sami `sys` is builtin module. There is very little chance it's a problem. Go watch your friend actually execute the program. *Where* did it work?  Pasted into some online evaluator?

Comment: @DanielRoseman No, it dosn't let me. It just shows me the error after python (script name) .py

Comment: Er, no, that doesn't make sense. Command-line arguments are what *you* type in after the name of the script. There is nothing to "not let" you do that.

Comment: Oh nvm lol, I used the "run" option in python IDLE. Yeah It worked now thanks. I used "python" then the name of the file. Instead I should have just wrote the name of the file and the 1 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to execute your program without specifying the parameters this is why you get this exception.

You can run your program from the command line by typing:

`python nameOfProgram.py argument1 argument2`

**Example:** [image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are not calling the script in the right way. Since you are taking arguments from user and if user does not specify the arguments, ERROR comes in.

Please see the following image:
[image]

A better way would be to use the following code:

```
import sys

if ( len(sys.argv) != 4) :
    print ("Please type correct input command. Correct command -> python <file name> <digit 1> <digit 2>")

else:
    v0 = float(sys.argv[1])
    t = float(sys.argv[2])
    g = 9.81
    x = v0 * t - 0.5 * g *t **2
    print (x)
```